# Transfprm wide data into long by mutationg some variable and keeping some variable as same as before

Tags: r, panel

I have a dataset of 6000 villages with variables like population(which I keep constant according to base year). There are three more variables project_1, project_2 and project_3 which gives the details when the project was implemented in this village. This is how the data looks like.

```
| village | population | project_1 | project_2 | project_3 |
|---------|------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| A       | 100        | 2002      |           |           |
| B       | 200        |           | 2003      | 2002      |
| C       | 150        | 2004      |           |           |
| D       | 175        |           |           | 2005      |
```

I want to transform this data into long-form(look below). So the basically the project variable becomes a dummy and take a value =1 when the project is implemented and remains equal to 1 thereafter.

```
| village | population | year | project_1 | project_2 | project_3 |
|---------|------------|------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| A       | 100        | 2001 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| A       | 100        | 2002 | 1         | 0         | 0         |
| A       | 100        | 2003 | 1         | 0         | 0         |
| A       | 100        | 2004 | 1         | 0         | 0         |
| A       | 100        | 2005 | 1         | 0         | 0         |
| B       | 200        | 2001 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| B       | 200        | 2002 | 0         | 0         | 1         |
| B       | 200        | 2003 | 0         | 1         | 1         |
| B       | 200        | 2004 | 0         | 1         | 1         |
| B       | 200        | 2005 | 0         | 1         | 1         |
| C       | 150        | 2001 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| C       | 150        | 2002 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| C       | 150        | 2003 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| C       | 150        | 2004 | 1         | 0         | 0         |
| C       | 150        | 2005 | 1         | 0         | 0         |
| D       | 175        | 2001 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| D       | 175        | 2002 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| D       | 175        | 2003 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| D       | 175        | 2004 | 0         | 0         | 0         |
| D       | 175        | 2005 | 0         | 0         | 1         |
```

I have tried this code but so far it's not working.

```
temp_long <- reshape(data = temp,
             idvar= "village",
             varying = 3:5,
             sep= "",
             timevar= "year",
             times = c(2001,2002,2003,2004,2005),
             new.row.names= 1:100000,
             direction = "long")
```

Comment: Hi, welcome could you please dput(head(yourdata)) the little ascii table is insufficient to help you best

Comment: Thanks a lot Chuck. I have posted dput just here. But I guess Martin already answered. Thanks a lot. `structure(list(key = c("057091", "057296", "057802", "057806", 
"058105", "058309"), TOT_POP = c(795, 378, 669, 3760, 55, 933
), road_comp_date_upg_year_final = c(2009, 2004, 2006, 2006, 
2008, 2012), road_award_date_upg_year_final = c(2008, 2003, 2005, 
2005, 2007, 2010), road_comp_date_stip_upg_year_final = c(2009, 
2003, 2006, 2006, 2008, 2011)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Hello Chuck! The issues are still not solved. You help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well if your `dput` is correct you need to change `expand.grid(year=2001:2005` to years that actually cover your data then his solution works again.  That's why I asked for the dput the details matter

Comment: Sorry for confusion. But I adjusted the years when I tried it. I only wrote the year as 2001:2005 as I friend to make the question shorter. But in dput it is the actual time frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your data are:

```
df <- read_table2("village population project_1 project_2 project_3
A 100 2002 NA NA
B 200 NA 2003 2002
C 150 2004 NA NA
D 175 NA NA 2005")
```

Using `dplyr`:

```r
df %>%
  merge(expand.grid(year=2001:2005, village=.$village), by="village") %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("project_"), ~ as.numeric(replace_na(.x <= year, 0)))) %>%
  select(village, population, year, starts_with("pro"))
```

yields

```r
   village population year project_1 project_2 project_3
1        A        100 2001         0         0         0
2        A        100 2002         1         0         0
3        A        100 2003         1         0         0
4        A        100 2004         1         0         0
5        A        100 2005         1         0         0
6        B        200 2001         0         0         0
7        B        200 2002         0         0         1
8        B        200 2003         0         1         1
9        B        200 2004         0         1         1
10       B        200 2005         0         1         1
11       C        150 2001         0         0         0
12       C        150 2002         0         0         0
13       C        150 2003         0         0         0
14       C        150 2004         1         0         0
15       C        150 2005         1         0         0
16       D        175 2001         0         0         0
17       D        175 2002         0         0         0
18       D        175 2003         0         0         0
19       D        175 2004         0         0         0
20       D        175 2005         0         0         1
```

With your `dput` data

```r
df2 <- structure(list(key = c("057091", "057296", "057802", "057806",  "058105", "058309"), TOT_POP = c(795, 378, 669, 3760, 55, 933 ), road_comp_date_upg_year_final = c(2009, 2004, 2006, 2006,  2008, 2012), road_award_date_upg_year_final = c(2008, 2003, 2005,  2005, 2007, 2010), road_comp_date_stip_upg_year_final = c(2009,  2003, 2006, 2006, 2008, 2011)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and the adjusted code

```r
df2 %>%
  merge(expand.grid(year=2001:2015, key=.$key), by="key") %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("road_"), ~ as.numeric(replace_na(.x <= year, 0)))) %>%
  select(key, TOT_POP, year, starts_with("road"))
```

creates

```r
      key TOT_POP year road_comp_date_upg_year_final road_award_date_upg_year_final road_comp_date_stip_upg_year_final
1  057091     795 2001                             0                              0                                  0
2  057091     795 2002                             0                              0                                  0
3  057091     795 2003                             0                              0                                  0
4  057091     795 2004                             0                              0                                  0
5  057091     795 2005                             0                              0                                  0
6  057091     795 2006                             0                              0                                  0
7  057091     795 2007                             0                              0                                  0
8  057091     795 2008                             0                              1                                  0
9  057091     795 2009                             1                              1                                  1
10 057091     795 2010                             1                              1                                  1
11 057091     795 2011                             1                              1                                  1
12 057091     795 2012                             1                              1                                  1
13 057091     795 2013                             1                              1                                  1
14 057091     795 2014                             1                              1                                  1
15 057091     795 2015                             1                              1                                  1
16 057296     378 2001                             0                              0                                  0
17 057296     378 2002                             0                              0                                  0
18 057296     378 2003                             0                              1                                  1
19 057296     378 2004                             1                              1                                  1
20 057296     378 2005                             1                              1                                  1
```

Comment: Hello Martin! Thanks for your message. Maybe I am doing something wrong because this is what I am getting the wrong result when I implemented the code suggested by you. For instance, for Project 1 in village A, my resulting data is 2002 for all the year 2001-2005

Comment: Do you get any error messages? The shown code with the result is what I get when I run it.

Comment: Martin look at his `dput` he gave us wrong years for the expand.grid

Comment: Based on the data you posted (I named them `df2`), the code should be: `df2 %>%
  merge(expand.grid(year=2001:2015, key=.$key), by="key") %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("road_"), ~ as.numeric(replace_na(.x <= year, 0)))) %>%
  select(key, TOT_POP, year, starts_with("road"))`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. when I am using the new code with df2 on the dput I posted. I am still getting the same result which is " for Project 1 in village A, my resulting data is 2002 for all the year 2001-2005". Even with your df answer, when I am running as it is the problem still persists.

Comment: @Fuser I am confused. I adjusted my answer and put your data and the new code in there. I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: I will try to make my query as understandable as I can. Using the dput I put and your new code. This is the dput of the data afterwards: structure(list(key = c("057091", "057091", "057091", "057091", 
"057091", "057091"), TOT_POP = c(795, 795, 795, 795, 795, 795
), year = 2001:2006, road_comp_date_upg_year_final = c(2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009), road_award_date_upg_year_final = c(2008, 
2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008), road_comp_date_stip_upg_year_final = c(2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Since I don't know why this isn't working for you: please type in `packageVersion("dplyr")`. It should be `1.0.0`.

Comment: My dplyr version is "dplyr_0.8.4 ". I will update it to 1.0.0 and try again. Do you also think it might be a result of possible conflict with other packages like plyr ?

Comment: So if you are satisfied, feel free to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). :-)